# Is switch-case sufficient to create multiple steps in a console app for modularization?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, switch-statement, console-application

I want to modify a console app, to modularize it (in C#). **The output should ask input by module so that there are two steps before reaching operation.** First is Module and second is Operation on that Module. For example current output is:

```
1. Add a member to A
2. View all members of A
3. Add a member to B
4. View all members of B
5. Add a member to C
6. View all members of C
```

I am using switch case statement to choose an option in user input and perform operation on it. After modularization, I want to get an output like:

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
```

After selecting 1 as user input, the output should be like:

```
1.1. Add element to A
1.2. View all elements of A
```

and so on for the rest of the user inputs. Now again when I enter 1.1. or 1.2., the final operation gets performed and the method is called. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a simple switch menu, just see my demo:

Feel free to modify this code according to your needs.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainMenu();
            Console.ReadLine();
            int MainMenu()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease select menu item (key in 1-3): ");
                    Console.WriteLine("1.A");
                    Console.WriteLine("2.B");
                    Console.WriteLine("3.C");
                    int choice; 
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out choice);
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1: AMenu(); break;
                        case 2://to do
                                break;
                        case 3://to do
                                break;

                        default: Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid input!\n"); break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIf you want to continue, press y, otherwise, press any other key!");

                    string ct = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ct != "y")
                        break;
                }
                return 0;
            }

            int AMenu()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease select menu item (key in 1.1-1.2): ");
                    Console.WriteLine("1.1. Add element to A");
                    Console.WriteLine("1.2. View all elements of A");
                    double choice;
                    double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice);
                    if (choice == 1.1) choice = 1;
                    else if (choice == 1.2) choice = 2;
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1: Console.WriteLine("Add element to A"); ; break;
                        case 2: Console.WriteLine("View all elements of A"); break;
                        default: Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid input!\n"); break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIf you want to continue, press y, otherwise, press any other key!");
                    string ct = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ct != "y")
                        break;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output：

[image]

If you have questions about my code, please comment below.

Answer (score 1):

If i got that correctly, you want to create an interactive CLI (Command Line Interface) menu with submenus.

For that purpose you could look online for a C# MVC CLI framework with the features you want (some good googling keywords might be "*c# cli menu*" and equivalent phrasing)

If you want to implement it yourself, consider first a separation of UI and Logic.
Your UI classes should only be concerned with the UI current state and user inputs.
In order to call the logic dynamically, a dictionary of callbacks in the View class might be a simple solution, as in *upon confirmation, given the current  state call callbacks[selection] if criterias are met*

As an ending note, i think you're overengineering it. A simpler indentation could do the trick easier, since we're talking about a CLI.

```
1. A
   1.1 view member
   1.2 add member
2. B
   2.1 whatever
```